# pandas to_sql function doesn't work when if_exists='replace'

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a python 3 script that I was using to write to redshift and it was working fine. We recently started moving to snowflake and it doesn't seem to work. specifically `if_exists = 'replace'` seems to be the problem. If i replace that with `if_exists='append'`, it works just fine, but I need to clear and replace the data for my use case.
I have permissions to drop and recreate the table, so that is not necessarily the problem.  Any help is appreciated.

```
data.to_sql('tableabc',
                    con=engine,
                    schema=schema,
                    index=False,
                    if_exists='replace',
                    method='multi',
                    chunksize=50000)
```

Error:

```
(<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError'>, NoSuchTableError('tableabc'), <traceback object at 0x7f3f2f4d5808>)
```

Comment: The error indicates that it is having a problem finding the table. Given that, try putting the table name in uppercase (and the schema name if necessary). Snowflake can be a bit sensitive about the case of object names

Comment: As Nick mentioned, the case of the table name could be the issue here. In Redshift all table names are converted to lower case regardless of how the CREATE statement is written. In Snowflake it depends on whether "quotes" were used around the table name when the CREATE was run. Without quotes all table names are converted to uppercase, with quotes table names are created exactly as specified, e.g. tableabc => TABLEABC, "tableabc" => tableabc. If the table name was created used quotes and is not uppercase, it must always be referenced using quotes in any queries.

Comment: As a test or quick fix you could try just using an uppercase table name e.g. TABLEABC and see if that works